# Rails 6 data aren't showing up on heroku local and on application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, postgresql, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy rails backend and react frontend app on Heroku. The frontend works fine but the data are not showing up on the Heroku site and on `heroku local`. It works perfectly on localhost.

Here is the url: https://smile.herokuapp.com/

I am using two different APIs, one of which is the Stripe API.

After deploying the application to Heroku, I migrated the database

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
heroku run rake db:seed
```

Once again, the application works locally but on Heroku, the database is missing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what database do you use?

Comment: postgreSQL @7urkm3n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue in the URL, read these two [One](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) |  [Two](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2386#issuecomment-304462556)

Check `CharityIndex.js` line 21 `fetch('http://localhost:3001/charities')`.

Its supposed to be `/charities`, you can test it with curl:

`curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" 'https://smile.herokuapp.com/charities'`

Try sample below:

```
  componentDidMount(){
    fetch(`/charities`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(charityData => {
        // debugger
        console.log(charityData);
        this.setState({
          charity: charityData
        })
    }
  )
```

Comment: Thanks!!! The data is up now but the descriptions and images are still not there. Any suggestion? @7urkm3n

Comment: @Sam make sure about urls, i believe you have the same issue again. To debug, check console on production and play around you will find out [gonna improve your debugging skill] ))